# Push notifications using Google Firebase with Phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a simple test app for testing push notifications.

I have installed the plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push), and followed all the installation instructions.

I receive an registration id ondeviceready, and when I use the php script to send a notification to that id it returns a success response from the google api, however no notification is appearing on the mobile device.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Push demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "my sender id"}});
            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                console.log(data.registrationId);
            });

            push.on('notification', function(data) {
                console.log(data.title + " Message: " + data.message);
            });

            push.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Push Notification Example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**pushTest.php**

```
<?php

define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'secret key here');

$registrationIds = array(
    'long device id here'
);

$msg = array(
    'message' => 'Test msg',
    'title' => 'Test title',
    'subtitle' => 'Test subtitle',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1
);

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data' => $msg
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

**PHP response**

```
{"multicast_id":xxxxxx,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:xxxxxxxxxx"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things, tried the "cordova-plugin-firebase" plugin and the "cordova-plugin-fcm" but I got an error that was identical from both plugins (don't remember the exact error message) however the problem was that I had only added "google-services.json" (android) to the root of the project, which I got from the firebase console and not the "GoogleService-Info.plist" (iOS).

However I actually ended up using the plugin "phonegap-plugin-push". I recreated the project with phonegaps push template, and suddenly it seemed to work.

If you are setting up push notifications for iOS don't forget to upload your push certificate in firebase console, if you are enabling gcm push for ios.

Answer (score 0):

**[GCM](https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send) no longer works**.

**[FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is the new GCM**.

In my apps, I use [this plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) to send push notification on Android/iOS.

You can read [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to know how to send push notification from server side.

Comment: I use FCM, but with the GCM plugin (phonegap-plugin-push) and it actually works now. I used the same setup and I wrote above, only thing different was I reinstalled my app using phonegaps push template. And I have activated GCM push for iOS in the Firebase console.